# How can I add XML to an HTML page with a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I would like to add XML to my HTML page. I would like the Topic to display as an 'h3', the content to display as a 'p' and the url to display within a 'a href'.

**XML**

```
<linkedin>
<discussion>
    <topic>This is the discussion name</topic>
    <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ligula mi, convallis eget iaculis id, euismod non arcu. Morbi porta.</content>
    <url>http://www.linkedin.com/groups/</url>
</discussion>
```

Here's how I would like the outputted HTML to look:

```
<h3>This is the discussion name</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ligula mi, convallis eget iaculis id, euismod non arcu. Morbi porta.</p>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groups/"></a>
```

Many Thanks, I hope this explanation of what I'm stuck on makes sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense.  What exactly are you "stuck on"?  How are you currently attempting to add the XML?

Comment: Would you like the XML transformed into HTML?

Comment: I just like the <topic>, <content> and <url> from the XML file to show on any HTML page. I just need to know what the HTML would be to extract this information from the XML file?

Comment: You can't extract data from XML using HTML. If you are doing this on the client you either need to use XSLT (if loading the XML in the browser window) or JavaScript (if loading it via Ajax)

Comment: Any examples of using XSLT or JavaScript, or if it's simple enough provide the code by one of the methods? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE** : This is as simple as it gets. It doesn't handle cases where any of the child nodes aren't present.

Just to get you started using an ajax request.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js" defer = "defer"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS (script.js)**

```
function getXML() {
    var xmlhttp,xmlDoc;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "your-xml-file.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    showDiscussions(xmlDoc);
}

function showDiscussions(xmlDoc) {
    var discHolder = document.createElement("DIV"),
        disc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("discussion");
    for (var i = 0, j = disc.length; i < j; i++) {
        var topic = document.createElement("h3"),
            content = document.createElement("p"),
            url = document.createElement("a");

        topic.innerHTML = disc[i].getElementsByTagName("topic")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        discHolder.appendChild(topic);
        content.innerHTML = disc[i].getElementsByTagName("content")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        discHolder.appendChild(content);
        url.href = disc[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        url.innerHTML = disc[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        discHolder.appendChild(url);

    }

    document.body.appendChild(discHolder);
}

getXML();
```

I will also recommend using [**jquery**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)